# Transform table into dataframe R

Tags: r, datatable, count

Say we have the following data:

```
user <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
type <- c('new', 'recent', 'recent', 'old', 'recent', 'new', 'new', 'old', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'recent')
df <- data.frame(user, type)
```

If we compute the table, we get the following:

```
table(df$type) 
>   new    old recent 
     6      2      4
```

I am looking for a function that takes in this table data and transforms it into a dataframe, regardless of the number of columns.
Ideally, the dataframe would look like this:

```
type     count 
new        6
old        2
recent     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the job:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(table(df$type))
> df2
    Var1 Freq
1    new    6
2    old    2
3 recent    4
```

You can rename Var1 and Freq if you want:

```
colnames(df2) <- c("type", "count")
> df2
    type count
1    new     6
2    old     2
3 recent     4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options

```
> stack(table(df$type))
  values    ind
1      6    new
2      2    old
3      4 recent

> as.data.frame(table(df$type))
    Var1 Freq
1    new    6
2    old    2
3 recent    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `count` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
count(df, type, name = 'count')
    type count
1    new     6
2    old     2
3 recent     4
```